# Scrolling using touch not working on Panel In c# windows 32 application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, windows-forms-designer

I am making win32 c# windows application on touch screen device. There is one form having width (800px) which has one panel(Main panel: width 780px). This panel has autoscroll true. I am adding panels(UserDetailRow: width 100px) to this panel dynamically(call an api, fetch data and draw controls on panel) . this panel contains name , address etc of user represented as labels.

suppose If my Api brings 30 records then 30 panels are drawn on main panel and scroll bar is visible. My problem is that scroller is working fine using mouse anywhere on Mainpanel.

But when I use touch to scroll then touch only works on area on main panel where UserDetailRow does not takes up space i.e. (780px-100px) if i swipe up or down on the userdetailrow panels the touch does not work.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Winforms has no built-in support for touch, but it can easily be added. Google "winforms wm_gesture", lotsa hits.  But it is probably worthwhile to dig in a bit to find out why the "legacy support" doesn't get the job done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wintouch/windows-touch-gestures-overview

Comment: but It is working.On same form if i swipe on area on mainpanel where my userdetail row does not take up space .

Comment: Try to substitute your scrollable Panel container with a Custom Control, derived from Panel. Set these styles in its constructor `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`. Also set `this.TabStop = true;` (after you have set the styles).

Comment: @Jimi i will check this too